# Error when trying to scaffold an Angular component

Tags: jss

With a fresh install of the jss cli and creating an Angular application `jss create test-app angular` when I try to generate a component I get the following error:

```
Component testComponent is scaffolding.
Next steps:
* Define the component's data in sitecore/definitions/components/testComponent.sitecore.ts
* Implement the Angular component in /src/app/components/testComponent
* Add the component to a route layout (/data/routes) and test it with jss start

Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-app@11.0.0 scaffold: `ng generate @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-angular-schematics:jss-component "testComponent"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the testtest@11.0.0 scaffold script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jonathank/.npm/_logs/2018-12-10T14_51_40_563Z-debug.log
```

One thing I notice is that the scaffold script is not in the 'scripts' directory. Any advice as to how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug caused by breaking changes in Angular Schematics.

I have [opened a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/90) to track it - your feedback on the way it gets fixed is welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I thought I was going crazy!